# How do i input a matrix from sys.stdin in python without loosing its 2d structure and at the same time be able to use numpy operations on it?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to take the matrix and use it further for computations. But I keep getting this error everytime I use numpy.loadtext(sys.stdin)

```
Error : File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/io.py", line 630, in loadtxt
    X.append(tuple([conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]))
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): <open
```

---

code from comment:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import sys 
import numpy as np 
c = np.zeros(shape=(2,2)) 
c = np.loadtxt(sys.stdin) 
d=[0.0,0.0] 
for i in range(0,1): 
     d[i]=np.linalg.det(c) 
     print d[i]
```

Comment: Please show your input as well.

Comment: #!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import numpy as np
c = np.zeros(shape=(2,2))
c = np.loadtxt(sys.stdin)
d=[0.0,0.0]

for i in range(0,1):
    d[i]=np.linalg.det(c)
    print d[i]

Comment: check the comment above @Roland Smith

Comment: I'm primarily writing a map reduce job on a hadoop cluster using python. I cant seem to get the mappers input ....The above code is for reducing

Comment: Practice using `loadtxt` on small files, as show in its documentation.  Why are trying to use `stdin` for this purpose?

Comment: So what should be used in this scenario instead of loadtxt? @hpaulj

Comment: Do you understand how `loadtxt` can be used with ordinary files?  Does your `stdin` file look anything like that?  Without information about your input we can't help you.  Your first comment shows your code, not the contents that `loadtxt` will try to parse.

Comment: Yea my input is basically a text.txt file with a random matrix (any size preferably small) . I use loadtxt in the mapper code to read the text file get the matrix . and then i have to print it in such a way that the reducer can read it .How do i do this? @hpaulj

Comment: Are you reading `text.txt` or `stdin`?  What does the text in that file look like?  In other words, what does that 'random matrix' look like?  If you haven't gotten past the `loadtxt`, the rest of your code doesn't matter.

Comment: When I place the command in hadoop it usually requires the mapper ,reducer ,input directory and output directory. Even though the input directory has a .txt file the hadoop framework converts this into a sys.stdin file. So my mapper also reads it as numpy.loadtxt(sys.stdin) ..The output of the mapper is usually printed using print . hadoop again puts this to sys.stdin . so now i have to read this again from reducer as sys.stdin . This is is where the error comes ...gives the error i posted in the question @hpaulj

Answer (score 1):

`np.loadtxt(stdin)` reads the input, line by line.  It splits the line on `delimiter` (here the default white space), and then tries to convert each string into a float.  In short:

```
In [49]: txt="""12.23 23.2
    ...: 233 2.23
    ...: """

In [50]: for lines in txt.splitlines():
    ...:     print [float(i) for i in lines.split()]
    ...:     
[12.23, 23.2]
[233.0, 2.23]
```

Does the `stdin` from `hadoop` framework look anything like that?

I keep asking - what does the `stdin` text look like.

Comment: Oh ok. It looks like :- Just an example [[ 1.  4.  2.  6.  6.]
 [ 2.  5.  6.  0.  7.]
 [ 3.  8.  2.  9.  5.]
 [ 4.  8.  7.  8.  8.]]  @hpaulj

Comment: Look at my answer to another recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36520026/901925

Comment: Yeah I've just formated my output to give float and then the np.loadtxt was working . Thanks a lot anyways , your answer was a great help @hpaulj