# Using numpy.genfromtxt how to parse a CSV field with the following format?

Tags: python, parsing, csv, numpy

I'm trying to parse a CSV file in which I have a field formatted in the following way:

```
[float,float,float]
```

the problem is that genfromtxt recognizes the commas inside my array as delimiter for the CSV row. How can I avoid such thing? What I'm doing now is:

```
genfromtxt(csv, skip_header=2, dtype=None, delimiter=',')
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`genfromtxt` expects rows like

```
float, float, float
float, float, float
```

It does not handle quotes or brackets.  In other words, the true csv structure is simple 2d, without internal groupings or 'fields'.

You can give `genfromtxt` a more complex `dtype` which does add structure.

The Python `csv` reader can handle quotes, and I suspect you can instruct it to treat [] like quotes.  But the result will be one string for the 'quoted' text.

`genfromtxt` accepts input from any iterable.  So you could write a little function that reads the file line by line, removes the brackets, adds delimiters as needed, and passes that line on to `genfromtxt`.

For a start, and especially for small files, load the whole thing as a list of lines (`readlines`), and massage those lines into flat delimited strings. Then give that to `genfromtxt`.